# Joining tables doubles the values

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
value1 INT NOT NULL,
value2 INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    table1_id INT NOT NULL,
    valuex INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, value1, value2)
VALUES
    (1, 10, 15),
    (2, 5 ,  3);

INSERT INTO table2 (id, table1_id, valuex)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 15),
    (2, 1, 25),
    (3, 2, 14),
    (4, 2, 10);
```

With this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`table1`.`id`) AS `orders`, 
   SUM(`value1`) as `sum_value1`, SUM(`value2`) as `sum_value2`, 
   SUM(`valuex`) as `sum_valuex` 
FROM `table1` 
     INNER JOIN `table2` 
         ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`table1_id`
```

I get the output:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
+ orders | sum_value1 | sum_value2 |sum_valuex +
+----------------------------------------------+
+    4   |     30     |     36     |    64     +
+----------------------------------------------+
```

But I have only two orders in table1. I know the duplication is being made because of the join, but how can I fix that with adding sum_valuex?

My desired result would be:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
+ orders | sum_value1 | sum_value2 |sum_valuex +
+----------------------------------------------+
+    2   |     15     |     18     |    64     +
+----------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT: I can't use select within select

Comment: try using GROUP BY table1.id at the end of the query....

Answer (score 2):

This is how joins work.  If you don't want the rows to multiply before the aggregation, then aggregate *before* doing the `join`.

```
SELECT t2.orders, t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.sum_valuex
FROM `table1` INNER JOIN
     (SELECT table1_id, SUM(valuex) as sum_valuex, COUNT(*) as orders
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY table1_id
     ) t2
     ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Which table has the orders ? Right now, your count(table1.id) is counting the records in table 2.  (That's where this column is, in Table 2) if Table1 is the table with the orders in it then you should be counting the records in table 1

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct a.id) orders, 
    SUM(value1) as sum_value1`, SUM(value2) as sum_value2, 
    SUM(valuex) as sum_valuex 
FROM table1 a 
   JOIN table2 b 
     ON b.table1_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the desire result like this :

SELECT count(orders ) as orders, SUM(t1.value1) as value1, SUM(t1.value2) as value2, SUM(t2.sum_valuex)   as sumvaluex
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT table1_id, SUM(valuex) as sum_valuex, COUNT(*) as orders
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY table1_id
     ) t2
     ON t1.id = t2.table1_id

Please dont forget to mark my answer:)